# Merge multiple key in dictionary with same values inside an array

Tags: python

I need to merge three dictionaries with array values into a single dict based on if they have same values inside the array. The dictionaries is like this:

```py
data = {
'A1':['Cheese','Cupcake', 'Salad','Sandwich'],
'A2':['Cheese','Cupcake', 'Pasta','Pudding'],
'A3':['Pudding','Pasta', 'Salad','Sandwich']
}
```

Then, the output would be like this:

```py
{
   'A1,A2':['Cheese','Cupcake']
   'A1,A3':['Salad', 'Sandwich']
   'A2,A3':['Pudding','Pasta']
}
```

I've tried this:

```py
tmp = {}
for key, value in data.items():
  if value in tmp:
    tmp[value].append(key)
  else:
    tmp[value] = [ key ]
print(tmp)
```

But it only works if the values isn't a list or array. Any solution?

Comment: Typo: `Chesee` => `Cheese`.

Comment: If A3 also had Cheese and Cupcake then would you want `'A1,A2,A3': ['Cheese','Cupcake']`?

Comment: @jarmod that's a good question (completely different logic!) ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given you use case, you could use [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) and [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) [`intersection`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.intersection):

```
data = {
'A1':['Cheese','Cupcake', 'Salad','Sandwich'],
'A2':['Cheese','Cupcake', 'Pasta','Pudding'],
'A3':['Pudding','Pasta', 'Salad','Sandwich']
}


from itertools import combinations

out = {f'{a},{b}': list(set(data[a]).intersection(data[b]))
       for a,b in combinations(data, 2)}
```

output:

```
{'A1,A2': ['Cupcake', 'Cheese'],
 'A1,A3': ['Sandwich', 'Salad'],
 'A2,A3': ['Pasta', 'Pudding']}
```